# Quaternionic representation

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, quaternions

Let $V$ be $G$-representation over quaternions $\mathbb{H}$. How to show that
$$
\mathbb{H} \otimes_\mathbb{C} V
$$
is canonically isomorphic to $V \oplus V$ as representation over $\mathbb{H}$?
In tensor product $\mathbb{H}$ is viewed as right $\mathbb{C}$-module, and $V$ is viewed as left $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, notice that representation $V$ over $\mathbb{H}$ is a complex representation and equivariant $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $J: V\to V,\,J^2=-1$, anticommuting with $I$, where $I$ is complex structure. If we replace $J$ by $-J$ we will get isomorphic representation with isomorphism given by $i$.

Let $V$ be quaternionic representation, $I$ and $J$ the corresponding maps. Let $W$ be $\mathbb{H} \otimes V$. On W there is well defined operator
$$
f: W \to W, \,  h \otimes v \mapsto hj\otimes Jv.
$$
We should check only
$$
f(hc\otimes v) = hcj\otimes Jv=hj\bar c\otimes Jv=hj\otimes \bar cJv=hj\otimes Jcv=f(h\otimes cv).
$$
Obviously $f^2=1$ and $f$ is $\mathbb{H}$-linear.
It easy to see that $W=W_1 \oplus W_2$,
$$
W_1 = Im(f-1)=Ker(f+1),
$$
$$
W_2 = Im(f+1) = Ker(f-1).
$$
There are maps
$$
a_1: V \to W_1, \, v\mapsto j\otimes Jv -1\otimes v,
$$
$$
a_2: V \to W_2,\, v \mapsto j\otimes Jv + 1\otimes v.
$$
They are complex-linear. Now look at the operator $J$:
$$
a_1(Jv) = -j\otimes v-1\otimes Jv=ja_1(v) \Rightarrow a_1J=ja_1,
$$
$$
a_2(Jv) = -j\otimes v + 1\otimes Jv = -ja_2(V) \Rightarrow a_2 J = -ja_2.
$$
But we have seen at the beginning that the sign of $J$ does not matter.